# d3.histogram - re-bin data from Crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram, crossfilter

d3's `histogram` layout expects data in a format like `[6, 9, 4, 2, 0, 6, 9]` and it creates tidy *bins* based on your domain, ticks, etc.

Crossfilter groups data a histogram structure (more or less), in a structure like this:

```
[
  { key: 0, value: 1 },
  { key: 1, value: 8 },
  { key: 3, value: 7 },
]
```

Notice that there's no object for key 2. The number of bins is just the number of distinct values from the data. Meanwhile `d3.histogram().threshholds(...)` would allow me to control how many bins I get.

I'd want to visualize the Crossfilter data and leverage `d3.histogram()`'s ability to make convenient bins. Is there some accessor function I can use to parse the Crossfilter data? Or do I need to coerce it into a regular array first?

Comment: This is what I don't understand: `d3.histogram` is designed to take raw data and put it into bins. Crossfilter does this same thing and the group output you show is already "binned" or aggregated. I would say either use Crossfilter or use `d3.histogram`, but I don't see a reason to use both. If the problem is more around how to use the Crossfilter output in a d3 visualization, we can address that, but there are also tutorials like http://eng.wealthfront.com/2012/09/05/explore-your-multivariate-data-with-crossfilter/

Comment: The key difference is the flexibility for the _number of bins_ from `d3.histogram`, using things like `d3.histogram.threshholds()`.
If the input data has a million distinct values but I only want 15 bins, for example.
Sorry, I should have been more clear about my reason for asking. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: Crossfilter's dimension.group takes an accessor function that lets you control how dimension keys are put into groups. Is that what you're looking for? https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group

Comment: I don't think so, or not exactly... I think I'd still have to tweak the data to ensure the array had contiguous values, and I'd need to know the min/max range to figure out how to get it into X number of bins, wouldn't I? With d3 I can just say `thresholds(x.ticks(15))` for ~15 ticks. If I'm going to be doing lots of operations on the input data, I'd might as well just coerce it into a structure for d3 at that point. Or can I do all that just with Crossfilter? I might be misunderstanding the docs.

Comment: You can do that all with Crossfilter and a wrapper group that adds bins if necessary, but you're probably better off just using d3.histogram and ditching Crossfilter unless you have a compelling need to use Crossfilter for this.

Comment: The end goal is to have 3 histogram bar charts with d3 brushes to control Crossfilter between them, similar to the example on the Crossfilter website. I have it working (more or less) without `d3.histogram` right now but not as cleanly as I'd like, and the data will eventually be dynamic with unknown ranges, etc., so I'd like to have one library or the other ensure that the bins are correct.

Comment: If you can share a working example I should be able to take a look and provide you an example approach at some point in the next couple days. Or someone else may get to it first!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still exploring this, but here's a `reduce` function that will flatten/expand the Crossfilter group data into an array for d3's `histogram` layout:

```
// reduce callback function
function flattenGroupData(flattened, currentRecord) {
  let value = currentRecord.key;
  let quantity = currentRecord.value;
  let expandedArray = Array(quantity).fill(value);
  return flattened.concat(expandedArray);
}

let groupData = myCrossfilterGroup.all();

let dataForD3 = groupData.reduce(flattenGroupData, []);
```